# File Upload with MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, mern

I need some input, as I am a newbie when it comes to MERN. I would like to upload a  file, such as a Word Docx file or text file, to my backend and execute an OS command on the file when received.

I see that there is a lot of express middleware that can be used for this task, such as Multer or Express-fileupload. Most of these libraries deal specifically with images though in examples.

I simply want to know what middleware the community would recommend for this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a MERN stack as well, and I'm using Multer. It took some getting used to as it was the first file upload library I've used, but overall I like it. I'd recommend. Express-fileupload seems pretty good as well. I think you'll be in good hands with either.

Comment: Thank you, multer looks pretty straight forward.